# cloud foundry cli login proxy

Tags: authentication, proxy, cloud-foundry

I am trying to connect to Cloud Foundry endpoint. I am working behind a proxy.

When I try to connect, I get the error below:

```
C:\WorkSpace\spring-bics-service-test>cf login

API endpoint> https://apps.xx.xxxx-xxx-cloud.com
FAILED
Error performing request: Get https://apps.xx.xxxx-xxx-cloud.com/v2/info: Proxy Authentication Required
```

I have set user variables for HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY in system advanced setting.
Does anyone know how to solve this? 
Is there any specific setting anywhere in Cloud Foundry or through cmd?

Comment: have you found the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the value you are specifying for the api endpoint is incorrect.

Is this a private pcf cloud ?
If yes, your api endpoint should be something like this "api.xxxx.com"

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/http-proxy.html, the relevant environment variables are `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` instead of the uppercase-variants you used.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `config.json` and set `AllowSSH` to `true`.